# Get three lowest values from Array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Assuming I got an JSON Object like this:

```
{"27":[2300,2300,2700,2300,2300,2300,2500,2300,2700,2300,2300,2300,2700,2300,2700,2300,2300,2300,2300,1900,2700,2300,2300,2300]}
```

I want to get the three lowest values from this array and store it as another array. I have tried `sort()` but experienced that it considers 10000 lower than 1300 for example.

**Question:** How would I get the three lowest value from the above JSON object and store it as an own array?

This is how I have tried to sort my array:

```
-prices[searchLog.PriceSearchId].sort();
```

Comment: You're sorting it incorrectly, but as you didn't post your code, we can't tell what the problem is ?

Comment: sort using your own callback function - ES2015+ would be `array.sort((a, b) => a-b).slice(0,3)`

Comment: please post your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/03e13wv4/

Comment: did you want the lowest three unique values ([ 1900, 2300, 2500 ]), or lowest three values ([ 1900, 2300, 2300 ])?

Comment: @JaromandaX I actually want the three lowest values, regardless if they exist multiple times or not.

Comment: kentor - @naveen has an answer that's good enough then

Comment: Depending on the number of items it might be more efficient to use **reduce()** rather than **sort()**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var prices = {
  "27": [2300, 2300, 2700, 2300, 2300, 2300, 2500, 2300, 2700, 2300, 2300, 2300, 2700, 2300, 2700, 2300, 2300, 2300, 2300, 1900, 2700, 2300, 2300, 2300]
};
var leastThree = prices["27"].sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}).slice(0, 3);
console.log(leastThree);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a fixed number of lowest values, there is no need to use `sort()`, whose time complexity is at best `O(N * log N)`.

The complexity of the following is `O(N)`.

```js
var prices = {
  "27": [2300, 2300, 2700, 2300, 2300, 2300, 2500, 2300, 2700, 2300, 2300, 2300, 2700, 2300, 2700, 2300, 2300, 2300, 2300, 1900, 2700, 2300, 2300, 2300]
};
var arr = prices['27'];

var lowest = new Array(3).fill(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);

for (var i = arr.length; --i >= 0; ) {
   var x = arr[i];
   // Update "lowest" array, as appropriate
   for (var j = 0; j < lowest.length; j++) {
     if (x < lowest[j]) {
       lowest.splice(j, 0, x);
       lowest.pop();
       break;
     }
   }
}

console.log(lowest);
```